# How to close infoWindow from sidebar in the second click in google maps api places

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm using this code: http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/places/places-search.html

I'd like on the second click of the sidebar, to close the infowindow (var iw).

```
    function isInfoWindowOpen(iw){
        var map = iw.getMap();
        return (map !== null && typeof map !== "undefined");
    }

tr.onclick=function(){
        google.maps.event.trigger(markers[i],'click');
        console.log('markers[i]: '+i);

    if (isInfoWindowOpen(iw)){
        // do something if IW is open
        iw.close(map,markers[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the showInfoWindow function in [the example](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/places/places-search.html) to check to see if the infowindow is open and the same infowindow, then just close it, otherwise do the required processing to get the contents.  Need to add a property to the marker so you can tell whether it is the same one or not.

```
  function showInfoWindow(i) {
    return function(place, status) {
      if (!!iw && iw._iwId == i) {
        iw.close();
        iw = null;
      } else {
        if (iw) {
          iw.close();
          iw = null;
        }
        if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
          iw = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: getIWContent(place),
            _iwId:i
          });
          iw.open(map, markers[i]);        
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

[working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_places-search_closeOn2ndClick.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the content to '' (standard way for closing the infowindow)
like this :

```
tr.onclick=function(){
        google.maps.event.trigger(markers[i],'click');
        console.log('markers[i]: '+i);

    if (isInfoWindowOpen(iw)){
        // do something if IW is open
        iw.close(map,markers[i]);
        // Set the content to ''
        iw.setContent('');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Goran but it didn't work. I updated the code with the function I call to check if the iw is open. Just in case ;o)

Comment: Strange I've recently implemented something similar .. you can check the example here that closes the infobox on hover event :
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13084631/google-maps-open-infowindow-on-mouseover-close-reopen-on-click)

Comment: Hi Goran, I checked your example but I didn't quite understand it, I think it's a bit different from what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Thing is that if you hover over some marker, it will close the previously opened infobox and open a new one. I guess the root issue you are having is related to closing the infobox-es..

Comment: Hi Goran, are you sure you send me the right example I only see one marker. onHover opens the iw. but that's all I can do ;O)

Comment: Yep its right, unfortunately it doesn't have more markers but you can add that easily enough in fiddle itself .. if you need to check how it's working. I used the same code today for some client case I had..