# Get Markers data below Googlemap as list items Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am having google map with 20 markers popup window is there.
Now, I want to capture details of all the markers show up as list(one by one). How can I do this below? 
I have pasted my whole code HTML+Javascript

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Search Near by location</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
   <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
        <style type="text/css">
            #map {
                height: 400px;
                width: 600px;
                border: 1px solid #333;
                margin-top: 0.6em;
            }
   
   
   
        </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){
  //get the checked nearby place
                $('.case').click(function(){
                    $(':checkbox').attr('checked',false);
                    $('#'+$(this).attr('id')).attr('checked',true);
                    search_types(map.getCenter());
                });
                
            });
            
         var map;
            var infowindow;
            var markersArray = [];
            var pyrmont = new google.maps.LatLng(20.268455824834792, 85.84099235520011);
            var marker;
            var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
   
   
            // var waypoints = [];                  
            function initialize() {
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                    center: pyrmont,
                    zoom: 14
                });
                infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
                //document.getElementById('directionsPanel').innerHTML='';
                search_types();
               }

            function createMarker(place,icon) {
                var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: place.geometry.location,
                    icon: icon,
                    visible:true  
                    
                });
   
                markersArray.push(marker);
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                    infowindow.setContent("<b>Name:</b>"+place.name+"<br><b>Address:</b>"+place.vicinity+"<br><b>Reference:</b>"+place.reference+"<br><b>Rating:</b>"+place.rating+"<br><b>Id:</b>"+place.id);
                    infowindow.open(map, this);
     
          //get the clicked ATM name
          document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=place.name;
                         // get the ATM address         
      document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML=place.vicinity;
              
     
                });
              
              
   }
   
       
            var source="";
            var dest='';
            
            function search_types(latLng){
                clearOverlays(); 
              
                if(!latLng){
                    var latLng = pyrmont;
                }
                var type = $('.case:checked').val();
                var icon = "https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/banking-7/24/banking-atm-1-48.png";
              
  
                var request = {
                    location: latLng,
                    radius: 2500,
                    types: [type] //e.g. school, restaurant,bank,bar,city_hall,gym,night_club,park,zoo
                };
               
                var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
                service.search(request, function(results, status) {
                    map.setZoom(14);
                    if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                            results[i].html_attributions='';
                            createMarker(results[i],icon);
       
       
                        }
      
      
                    }
     
                });
                
             }
            
         
            // Deletes all markers in the array by removing references to them
            function clearOverlays() {
                if (markersArray) {
                    for (i in markersArray) {
                        markersArray[i].setVisible(false)
                    }
                    //markersArray.length = 0;
      //document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = markersArray.length;    
                }
            }
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
            
            function clearMarkers(){
                $('#show_btn').show();
                $('#hide_btn').hide();
                clearOverlays()
            }
            function showMarkers(){
                $('#show_btn').hide();
                $('#hide_btn').show();
                if (markersArray) {
                    for (i in markersArray) {
                        markersArray[i].setVisible(true)
                    }
                     
                }
            }
            
            function showMap(){
                
                var imageUrl = 'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=mm&chs=24x32&chco=FFFFFF,008CFF,000000&ext=.png';
                var markerImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage(imageUrl,new google.maps.Size(24, 32));
                var input_addr=$('#address').val();
       geocoder.geocode({address: input_addr}, function(results, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                        var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                        var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
                        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                        if (results[0]) {
                            map.setZoom(14);
                            map.setCenter(latlng);
                            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                position: latlng, 
                                map: map,
                                icon: markerImage,
                                draggable: true 
                                
                            }); 
                            $('#btn').hide();
                            $('#latitude,#longitude').show();
                            $('#address').val(results[0].formatted_address);
                            $('#latitude').val(marker.getPosition().lat());
                            $('#longitude').val(marker.getPosition().lng());
                            infowindow.setContent(results[0].formatted_address);
                            infowindow.open(map, marker);
                            search_types(marker.getPosition());
                            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                                infowindow.open(map,marker);
                                
                            });
                        
                        
                            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() {
                              
                                geocoder.geocode({'latLng': marker.getPosition()}, function(results, status) {
                                    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                                        if (results[0]) {
                                            $('#btn').hide();
                                            $('#latitude,#longitude').show();
                                            $('#address').val(results[0].formatted_address);
                                            $('#latitude').val(marker.getPosition().lat());
                                            $('#longitude').val(marker.getPosition().lng());
           
          
           
                                        }
                                       
                                        infowindow.setContent(results[0].formatted_address);
                                        var centralLatLng = marker.getPosition();
                                        search_types(centralLatLng);
                                        infowindow.open(map, marker);
                                    }
                                });
        
                   
        
                            });
                                 
                        
                        } else {
                            alert("No results found");
                        }
                    } else {
                        alert("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
                    }
                });
                
            }   
                                 

$(function(){
 
    // add multiple select / deselect functionality
    $("#selectall").click(function () {
          $('.case').attr('checked', this.checked);
    });
 
    // if all checkbox are selected, check the selectall checkbox
    // and viceversa
    $(".case").click(function(){
 
        if($(".case").length == $(".case:checked").length) {
            $("#selectall").attr("checked", "checked");
        } else {
            $("#selectall").removeAttr("checked");
        }
 
    });
});
</SCRIPT>
  
    </head>
    <body>


        <label>Address: </label><input id="address"  type="text" style="width:400px;" value=""/>
       
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
   <input type="checkbox" name="mytype" class="case btn btn-primary"  id="btn"  value="atm" onClick="showMap();">ATM
    </label>
        <br/>
        <div id="map"></div>
        <input type="text" id="latitude" style="display:none;" placeholder="Latitude"/>
        <input type="text" id="longitude" style="display:none;" placeholder="Longitude"/>
       <!-- <input type="button"  id="hide_btn" value="hide markers" onClick="clearMarkers();" />-->
        <input type="button" id="show_btn"  value="atm" onClick="showMarkers();" style="display:none;" />

        <div id="test"></div>
  
   <p id="demo"></p>
   <p id="demo1"></p>
   <p id="demo3"></p>
   


    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Loop trough the markerArray??

Comment: @Jonasw I tried but it's returning last marker detail can you please suggest something

Comment: like this i have tried  
      for(var i = 0; i < results.length; i++){
      
       document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=place.name;
                         // get the ATM address         
      document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML=place.vicinity;
      }
        but it's not returing anythig as list item if i am not using for loop then it's returning one record

Comment: Place doesnt change. Also, innerHTML is overriding the existing content

Comment: Do sth like place=results[i] and to add content innerHTML+=place.name

Comment: oh ok so how can i iterate demo1 paragraph

Comment: Demo1 is overriden. So your loop will override its content, so youre just displaying one content

Comment: Is results an array of places?

Comment: @Jonasw it's returning one by one not like array

Comment: i think its better to use markersArray, i write an answer

Comment: related question: [How to close infoWindow from sidebar in the second click in google maps api places](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21469362/how-to-close-infowindow-from-sidebar-in-the-second-click-in-google-maps-api-plac)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to capture the data you want to display under the map in a appropriately scoped variable as you create the markers (in the createMarker function):

```
htmlStr += "<tr><td><b>Name:</b>" + place.name + "<br><b>Address:</b>" + place.vicinity + "<br><b>Reference:</b>" + place.reference + "<br><b>Rating:</b>" + place.rating + "<br><b>Id:</b>" + place.id + "</td></tr>";
```

Initialize the variable before the loop that creates the markers, finish it and put it in the div you want to display it at the end of the loop:

```
if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
  htmlStr = "<table border='1'><tbody>";
  for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    results[i].html_attributions = '';
    createMarker(results[i], icon);
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = htmlStr + "</tbody></table>";
}
```

**code snippet:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Search Near by location</title>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <style type="text/css">
    #map {
      height: 400px;
      width: 600px;
      border: 1px solid #333;
      margin-top: 0.6em;
    }
  </style>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      //get the checked nearby place
      $('.case').click(function() {
        $(':checkbox').attr('checked', false);
        $('#' + $(this).attr('id')).attr('checked', true);
        search_types(map.getCenter());
      });
    });
    var map;
    var htmlStr = '';
    var infowindow;
    var markersArray = [];
    var pyrmont = new google.maps.LatLng(20.268455824834792, 85.84099235520011);
    var marker;
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    function initialize() {
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        center: pyrmont,
        zoom: 14
      });
      infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
      search_types();
    }

    function createMarker(place, icon) {
      var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: place.geometry.location,
        icon: icon,
        visible: true
      });
      markersArray.push(marker);
      htmlStr += "<tr><td><b>Name:</b>" + place.name + "<br><b>Address:</b>" + place.vicinity + "<br><b>Reference:</b>" + place.reference + "<br><b>Rating:</b>" + place.rating + "<br><b>Id:</b>" + place.id + "</td></tr>";
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.setContent("<b>Name:</b>" + place.name + "<br><b>Address:</b>" + place.vicinity + "<br><b>Reference:</b>" + place.reference + "<br><b>Rating:</b>" + place.rating + "<br><b>Id:</b>" + place.id);
        infowindow.open(map, this);
      });
    }
    var source = "";
    var dest = '';

    function search_types(latLng) {
        clearOverlays();
        if (!latLng) {
          var latLng = pyrmont;
        }
        var type = $('.case:checked').val();
        var icon = "https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/banking-7/24/banking-atm-1-48.png";
        var request = {
          location: latLng,
          radius: 2500,
          types: [type] //e.g. school, restaurant,bank,bar,city_hall,gym,night_club,park,zoo
        };
        var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
        service.search(request, function(results, status) {
          map.setZoom(14);
          if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
            htmlStr = "<table border='1'><tbody>";
            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
              results[i].html_attributions = '';
              createMarker(results[i], icon);
            }
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = htmlStr + "</tbody></table>";
          }
        });
      }
      // Deletes all markers in the array by removing references to them

    function clearOverlays() {
      if (markersArray) {
        for (i in markersArray) {
          markersArray[i].setVisible(false)
        }
      }
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    function clearMarkers() {
      $('#show_btn').show();
      $('#hide_btn').hide();
      clearOverlays()
    }

    function showMarkers() {
      $('#show_btn').hide();
      $('#hide_btn').show();
      if (markersArray) {
        for (i in markersArray) {
          markersArray[i].setVisible(true)
        }

      }
    }

    function showMap() {
      var imageUrl = 'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=mm&chs=24x32&chco=FFFFFF,008CFF,000000&ext=.png';
      var markerImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage(imageUrl, new google.maps.Size(24, 32));
      var input_addr = $('#address').val();
      geocoder.geocode({
        address: input_addr
      }, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
          var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
          var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
          if (results[0]) {
            map.setZoom(14);
            map.setCenter(latlng);
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: latlng,
              map: map,
              icon: markerImage,
              draggable: true
            });
            $('#btn').hide();
            $('#latitude,#longitude').show();
            $('#address').val(results[0].formatted_address);
            $('#latitude').val(marker.getPosition().lat());
            $('#longitude').val(marker.getPosition().lng());
            infowindow.setContent(results[0].formatted_address);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
            search_types(marker.getPosition());
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
              infowindow.open(map, marker);
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() {
              geocoder.geocode({
                'latLng': marker.getPosition()
              }, function(results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                  if (results[0]) {
                    $('#btn').hide();
                    $('#latitude,#longitude').show();
                    $('#address').val(results[0].formatted_address);
                    $('#latitude').val(marker.getPosition().lat());
                    $('#longitude').val(marker.getPosition().lng());
                  }
                  infowindow.setContent(results[0].formatted_address);
                  var centralLatLng = marker.getPosition();
                  search_types(centralLatLng);
                  infowindow.open(map, marker);
                }
              });
            });
          } else {
            alert("No results found");
          }
        } else {
          alert("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
        }
      });
    }
    $(function() {
      // add multiple select / deselect functionality
      $("#selectall").click(function() {
        $('.case').attr('checked', this.checked);
      });
      // if all checkbox are selected, check the selectall checkbox
      // and viceversa
      $(".case").click(function() {
        if ($(".case").length == $(".case:checked").length) {
          $("#selectall").attr("checked", "checked");
        } else {
          $("#selectall").removeAttr("checked");
        }
      });
    });
  </SCRIPT>
</head>

<body>
  <label>Address:</label>
  <input id="address" type="text" style="width:400px;" value="" />
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="checkbox" name="mytype" class="case btn btn-primary" id="btn" value="atm" onClick="showMap();">ATM
  </label>
  <br/>
  <div id="map"></div>
  <input type="text" id="latitude" style="display:none;" placeholder="Latitude" />
  <input type="text" id="longitude" style="display:none;" placeholder="Longitude" />
  <!-- <input type="button"  id="hide_btn" value="hide markers" onClick="clearMarkers();" />-->
  <input type="button" id="show_btn" value="atm" onClick="showMarkers();" style="display:none;" />
  <div id="test"></div>
  <p id="demo"></p>
  <p id="demo1"></p>
  <p id="demo3"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, MarkersArray contains everything you need. Lets loop trough it.

```
for(i=0;i<MarkersArray;i++){
   marker=MarkersArray[i];
   container=document.body;//change to your element
   //create a new paragraph, and add it to the marker (if you need to change it later)
 marker.html=document.createElement("p");
  //add the name and vicinity to the paragraph
 marker.html.innerHTML=marker.name+":"+marker.vicinity;
  //put it on the site (into the container)
 container.appendChild(marker.html);
 }
```

Comment: Whenever you give an answer of the question, then add some description, what's wrong in OP's code and how to sort it out.